# How to download an image from server side to android using bytearray?

Tags: android, image, arrays, android-image

My Android colleague wants an image to be sent from `Java Server` side code, I tried using `byte-array-output stream`, which is the best way to send an image to `Android client`. How should the android code be to receive `byte-array`.

Comment: just search in SO you will find what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this things by byte array. This is my code for your reference :

```
String base64String = (String)sp.toString();
byte[] mediaData = Base64.decode(base64String, 0);                              write(notesList.get(position).getContent(), mediaData);
                                        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                                                notesList.get(position).getContent());
                                        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                                        if(notesList.get(position).getContent().contains(".pdf"))
                                        {
                                            Intent pdfOpenintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                            pdfOpenintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                            pdfOpenintent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                                            try {
                                                context.startActivity(pdfOpenintent);
                                            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else if(notesList.get(position).getContent().contains(".jpg") || notesList.get(position).getContent().contains(".jpeg") || notesList.get(position).getContent().contains(".png"))
                                        {
                                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + path), "image/*");
                                            context.startActivity(intent);
                                        }
                                        else if(notesList.get(position).getContent().contains(".xls"))
                                        {
                                            PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                            intent.setType("application/*");
                                            List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                                                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);


                                            if (list.size() > 0) {
                                                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/*");
                                                context.startActivity(intent);
                                            }
                                        }
```

Here, sp is the response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Hi parth welcome to stackoverflow.
There are saveral ways to do this task, which way you want to use, depends on your equirement.
Most common way is using Socket(it depends on requirement).

See this [example](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/01/transfer-image-between-android-devices.html). 
This example includes both client and server side coding.

Hope this helps.